# PHP MVC works locally but when uploaded to host fails

Tags: php, localhost, syntax-error

Everything is working fine on localhost/myweb but when i upload the folder myweb to my public_html directory i get error:

```
[16-Sep-2012 18:32:55] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92)  
state=1 in /home1/programw/public_html/myweb/index.php on line 7

[16-Sep-2012 18:32:55] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home1
/programw/public_html/myweb/index.php on line 7
```

on my index.php line 7 has this code:

```
   $app = new Core\Bootstrap();
```

i know something has to do with \ slash but i cant figure out what or how to fix it.

can anyone help me please? I also use .htaccess and inside .htaccess i have the following:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**SOLUTION**

i just found out that \ slash and namespacing is only supported in PHP 5.3 and my hosting for some reason didnt update their PHP to 5.3. If anyone knows a way around it  to work on 5.2 i will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will only work in PHP 5.3 and above. Your server is probably still running PHP 5.2

You can check this most simply through phpinfo(); or phpversion();

To fix, you'll need to remove the namesapces (which may be a big job with an external framework) or upgrade the server to PHP 5.3 or above (note that 5.2 is pretty old!)

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround for running PHP 5.3 code on PHP 5.2. Either you can

1. Convince your hosting company to upgrade to PHP 5.3 or greater
2. Find another hosting company that has PHP 5.3 or greater
3. Find a PHP 5.2 compatiable alternative to the package you are wanting to use.