# Site works locally on XAMPP but not when uploaded to the web error 500 htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a site that I have been working on locally using XAMPP in windows and it works fine. No errors it runs perfectly.

So I decided to upload it to the web. But now I get an error 500. My initial thought was that it has something to do the the .htaccess file but it works fine on xampp in my htdocs file.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451932/php-mvc-works-locally-but-when-uploaded-to-host-fails) and it made me think. When I upload my site via ftp it does into the folder `public_html/` so would I need to configure my .htaccess file for this?

The code for my .htaccess is shown below;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

My code is running the silex and symfony framework for routing so not sure if it has something do with this?

Below is my index.php file

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/provider/AuthenticationServiceProvider.php';
require_once 'src/provider/TutorServiceProvider.php';


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',
));

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Tutor\Provider\AuthenticationServiceProvider());

$app->register(new Tutor\Provider\TutorServiceProvider());

$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    $tutors = $app['tutor']->get_tutors();
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array('active_page' => 'home', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'tutors' => $tutors));
});

$app->get('/about-us', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('about-us.twig', array('active_page' => 'about-us', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/home-tuition', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('home-tuition.twig', array('active_page' => 'home-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/group-tuition', function() use($app) {
    $groups = $app['tutor']->get_group_tuition($app['auth']->get_user()['email']);
    return $app['twig']->render('group-tuition.twig', array('active_page' => 'group-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'groups' => $groups, 'user' => $app['auth']->get_user()));
});

$app->get('/group-tuition/{tutoremail}/{starttime}', function($tutoremail, $starttime) use($app) {
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    if (null !== $user && ($user['type'] == 'admin' || $user['email'] == $tutoremail)) {
        $group = $app['tutor']->get_group_tuition_details($tutoremail, $starttime);
        return $app['twig']->render('group-tuition-details.twig', array('active_page' => 'group-tuition', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'group' => $group));
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/group-tuition');
    }
});

$app->get('/contact-us', function() use($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('contact-us.twig', array('active_page' => 'contact-us', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->get('/tutor/{username}', function($username) use($app) {
    $tutor = $app['tutor']->get_tutor($username);
    if (null !== $tutor) {
        return $app['twig']->render('tutor.twig', array('active_page' => 'tutor', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'tutor' => $tutor));
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    }
});

$app->get('/login', function() use($app) {

    if ($app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app['twig']->render('login.twig', array('active_page' => 'login', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
    }
});

$app->post('/login', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    $password = $app['request']->get('password');
    if ($app['auth']->login($email, $password)) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('error','There was an error with you details please try again');
        return $app->redirect('/login');
    }
});

$app->get('/logout', function() use($app) {
    $app['auth']->logout();
    return $app->redirect('/');
});

$app->get('/register', function() use($app) {
    if ($app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app['twig']->render('register.twig', array('active_page' => 'register', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
    }
});


$app->post('/register', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    $password = $app['request']->get('password');
    $name = $app['request']->get('name');
    $address = $app['request']->get('address');
    $phone = $app['request']->get('phone');
    if ($app['auth']->register($email, $password, $name, $address, $phone, 'student')) {
        return $app->redirect('/');
    } else {
        return $app->redirect('/register');
    }
});



$app->get('/reset-password', function() use($app) {
        return $app['twig']->render('reset-password.twig',array('active_page' => 'reset-password','is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in()));
});

$app->post('/reset-password', function(Request $request) use($app){
    $email = $app['request']->get('email');
    if($app['auth']->sendEmail($email)){
        return $app->redirect('/reset-password');
    }
});

$app->get('/admin', function() use($app) {
    $tutor = $app['tutor']->get_tutors();
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    if (null !== $user && $user['type'] == 'admin' && null !== $tutor){
        return $app['twig']->render('admin.twig', array('active_page' => 'admin', 'is_user_logged_in' => $app['auth']->is_user_logged_in(), 'contacts' => $app['tutor']->get_user(), 'items' => $app['tutor']->get_user_id(), 'tutor' => $tutor));
    }else{
        return $app->redirect('/login');
    }
});



$app->post('/charge', function(Request $request) use($app) {
    $description = $app['request']->get('description');
    $tutoremail = $app['request']->get('tutoremail');
    $starttime = $app['request']->get('starttime');
    $user = $app['auth']->get_user();
    $studentemail = $user['email'];

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_fktchFYkd0XywraJftt8Z9uc");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $app['request']->get('stripeToken');

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 2000, // amount in cents, again
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "source" => $token,
            "description" => $description . ' paid by ' . $studentemail . ' for session ' . $tutoremail . '/' . $starttime
        ));
        $app['tutor']->add_group_tuition_booking($tutoremail, $starttime, $studentemail);
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // The card has been declined
    }
    return $app->redirect('/group-tuition');
});

$app->run();
```

I also had a read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451932/php-mvc-works-locally-but-when-uploaded-to-host-fails) and this said that namespaces are not available in php versions from before 5.3, so I checked the php version that my host is running by using the index.php file that included;

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

and this returned successfully the version 5.3.28 so assumed it could not be down to this.

my composer.json file below;

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.1",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.3",
        "symfony/console": "~2.3",
        "symfony/config": "^3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.3",
        "symfony/filesystem": "~2.3",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.3",
        "symfony/form": "^3.0",
        "symfony/locale": "~2.3",
        "symfony/process": "~2.3",
        "symfony/security": "~2.3",
        "symfony/serializer": "~2.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^3.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^3.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.3",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": ">=2.2.0,<2.4.0-dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "5.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.23",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log file? What does it says?

Comment: When in xampp it shows no errors since the 26 march 2016, I am not actually sure on how to check the error log file on my host. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: On CentOS is in `/var/log/php-fpm/`, it should be somwhere similar on others, and it's easy to google it for specific system. Tip: use tail like this `tail /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`

Comment: Sorry my reply must have been confusing I checked the error log within xampp and there are no errors since the 26th March 2016 as my site is working fine locally. However as it is not working on my host provider after I have uploaded it to their servers I am not sure how to check the error log there?

Comment: If you have SSH access, then like I wrote above. If not, look in their admin panel (like cPanel or Plesk). They surely have somewhere option to show you content of log file(s)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html
you will see this:

> PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.5.9

and you wrote that `phpinfo()` returned this:

> returned successfully the version 5.3.28

So, are you using older version of Symfony? At first it looks like you'll need to upgrade PHP (or downgrade Symfony...)

Comment: I just checked my version of php in xampp I have  php version 5.6.15. The web host that I am using has the php version 5.3.28. So I guess this is the problem then? I will have to take it up with my web host. I have uploaded my composer.json file

Comment: I think so. I advise you to request from your host to upgrade PHP because, for example, Traits were introduced in PHP 5.4 (and similar) so it will broke your code if you use it and so on...

Comment: Thank you so much it was down to the version. I did not realise I could change the version of php in my cpanel. Spent all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.